# Decimal vs. Double for small currency numbers that only get stored, not manipulated

Tags: c#, types, double, decimal, currency

I'm writing a small application that accesses an SQL database to retrieve information about some local events, including their prices, and allows creation and editing of new events as well as exporting formatted and filtered lists of those events for printing etc.

Now an event may have an entrance fee that is also represented in the data sets (MS SQL Server data type "money"), but I'm wondering which data type to use in my client application.

I know that you should always use Decimal for currency calculations because of its high precision - but I'm not going to do *any* calculations, it will only get entered as number with two decimal places and stored to the database, and later it gets loaded again and displayed or exported into a printable document - no calculations that could accumulate inaccuracies.

So which data type would you use in this case? Still go for Decimal just because it's money and don't care about the memory etc? Or use Double instead as it would be precise enough? Alternatively I could probably store the price in Cents as Integer as well. What type should I go for?

Comment: Why risk precision? Just go for decimals.

Comment: Even if you just enter `Double`, say, `123.45` it may be represented as `123.4499999999999` or `123.4500000000002` do you need to risk?

Comment: For all currency values please use decimal. That's the sole purpose of its existence..

Comment: SQL Server .NET reader maps [T-SQL money to .NET decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there's no reason to use anything else at this point

Comment: I think you already got the message. Make it a habit using Decimal for anything that touches currency.

Comment: I do not- Decimal is horrendously inefficient if you DO a lot of calculations.  And even with finance sometimes extreme precision is not really needed. I wish .NET would support decimal float as per IEEE specs - and Intel would get that into the hardware.

Comment: Precision is more important than performance in most cases. Especially if in the question is mentioned that no calculations will be done. So decimal is clearly the way to go.

Comment: Ohkay, I think I'll go for Decimal. Especially the argument that SQL's `money` data type converts to Decimal convinced me, so if you could post that as answer @Martheen, I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when dealing with existing data source, just follow what's already used. In this case, SQL Server .NET reader maps [money to decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means no awkward casting and nothing wasted in transmission.

TomTom's answer in his comment point the case when double can get the performance you needed with acceptable precision, but unless you're dealing with millions of calculations or starved in storage there's no reason to not use decimal for financial data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to store them and then print them as text then float or double will suffice (which one depends on how many total digits you'll need, not just decimal places). If you need up to 6 digits, a float will do; if you need up to 15 digits, you will need a double. (This follows from the "theory of round-tripping", which I have discussed often on my Web site, for example at http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/ ).

Caveat: the conversions in both directions (to floating-point, to text) must be done correctly. For example, they aren't (or at least weren't six years ago) done correctly in [SQLite](http://www.exploringbinary.com/fifteen-digits-dont-round-trip-through-sqlite-reals/). (I haven't studied MS SQL Server.) This alone may scare you back into using Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Decimal(x+2,2)` where x is the integer places you want to store

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  MyDecimalColumn decimal(5,2)
  ....    
);


public class MyTableObject{
  public decimal MyDecimalColumn {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with that or how to use it. Could you please add two lines of example code for clarification?

Comment: @ByteCommander just try to find the "longest" number you will need to process and then define the database decimal size (x value).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in hell. Sadly C# (or rather .NET) does not implement do not implement IEEE 754 2008 decimal float specs.

In your case I would suggest to use a float or double - float is likely good enough for SMALL currency numbers, if the resoltion is not good enough use double.

Make sure to output format every output with the exact number of digits "possible" as it is likely certain numbers are approximated (1.1 for example has no EXACT representation). Without a good format string you may get funny printing.

> Alternatively I could probably store the price in Cents as Integer as well.

That works - but it requires interesting playing around on every output obviously. As you do presentation only that is very doable. It also is very unneeded, IMHO.

Comment: So everybody is insisting on `Decimal` and you advise me **`float`**!? o.O I would not have expected that... Now I'm even more confused than half an hour ago.

Comment: For values that are naturally exact decimals, use decimal. For values that can't really be measured exactly, use float/double. So for prices, of course decimal is the way to go. Performance is a non-argument in most cases - don't micro-optimize.

Comment: Yeah, except if it is not a micro optimization. There are some of us doing work where the factor 10 roughly performance different comes up brutally. I happen to write statistical simulations and simulation frameworks in the financial area. In my world, this is all but a micro optimization. And in my world on the framework level we optimize the hell out of anything because time IS money - literally if your code runs on a distributed cluster 24/7 and you can shut down half of the machines if you are not an idiot programmer and write efficient code, and still make it in the same time.

Comment: But this question was not about your world.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DECIMAL` in SQL, often stores an int internally in the database, but the comma point is shifted left before printing by the second parameter. So `DECIMAL(5,2)` means that it can store a total of 5 digits, 2 of them will be behind the comma.

When working with currency, it is wize to either use decimal datatypes or perform all calculations and storage in cents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just store the price value and display it later, you can just use a string for that. This way there's zero conversion cost on storing and reading. It may use even less memory than Decimal for small values like this. Sometimes you'll need to convert between `,` and `.` depending on locales, but for a local event it may not matters a lot

The next best choice would be storing the cent value as Integer